# MomentJS - How to get 00:01:00.02 format from seconds.milliseconds value?

Tags: momentjs

My value is `60.02` so how can I transform it in **hours:minutes:seconds.milliSeconds** format to get `00:01:00.02` format using the momentJS library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use moment duration to format your time string

```
let seconds = '60.02';
moment.utc(moment.duration({
    seconds: seconds
}).asMilliseconds()).format('HH:mm:ss:SS');
```

For the whole moment duration docs see [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/)

Comment: I am not sure that it works correctly, i need 0 hours, 1 minute and 2 milliseconds as output.

Comment: sorry missunderstood your question. I edited my answer try it now

Comment: Now it's good format i think.

I would like to have only two symbols in milliseconds, if is possible. To have something like this: 12:10:30.05

Comment: Ok then you just need to remove on `S` from the format option, but then you cant display 2 milliseconds. you could only display 20 milliseconds

Comment: Now i am using this code:

    var time = number.toString().split('.')
    number = moment.utc(moment.duration({
        seconds: time[0] + '.' + time[1]
    }).asMilliseconds()).format('HH:mm:ss:SS')

it works well when i have number with a dot like this 10.10
but when i have integer or just 0 i have problem with that, is it possible to fix?

Comment: @Ess I edit it again if you use it like this any vaild second format should be fine. I tested it with `'60.02'`, `60`, `0` and `'0'`